# Hosting video on website

Tags: html, web, jekyll

I am hosting a website on aws, and I am writing it using jekyll. I want to post a video that I have created (not embedding from youtube). Right now I have a separate layout for video posting, in which I have:

In the frontmatter of my actual post I include the following line: video_source: "simvids/10-mites-random-shades-5x5.webm"

The simvids directory is in the same folder as the _site, _layouts, and _posts directory. The framework for the video loads, but the video itself does not. This leads me to think that the video tag is not the problem, but that I'm not directing properly to the video. Is my simvids directory in the wrong place? Is the error more subtle?

```
<video width="480" height="360" controls>
    <source src="{{ page.video_source | absolute_url }}" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use Cloudinary. I find this deals with most of my CDN needs and is mostly free. Excellent for video and images and is adaptable to a filing system. I also use compressor.io to shrink my images down and Advanced Video Compressor to compress the file sizes for video.

This is my video embed code:

```
<video class="videoSpotlight" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/cloudinarylinkhere" controls></video>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you forgot the `absolute_url` filter. Does your video tag look something like this ?

```
<video class="yourClass" src="{{ page.video_source | absolute_url }}" controls></video>
```

If not post it so we can know what's wrong.

Comment: I did not originally, though I added it on your suggestion but was met with the same error. I've added a line to my question showing what my tag looks like.

Comment: I've since tried the exact formatting you provided, combining all of the content to a single tag. Still no resolution.